# android studio java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android-studio

So I am working on app which need to write in sd card, when I try to write in file, it says: `java.lang.NullPointerException`
Here's my code:

```
public void goWrite() {
    File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DIR);
    sdPath.mkdir();
    Toast.makeText(this ,"" + sdPath ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    File sdFile = new File(sdPath ,filename);
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sdFile));
        bw.write("Correct answers - " + correct + "\nincorrect answers - " + incorrect);
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here's my manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".indentification"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".trivia"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_indentification" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Summary"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_summary" >
    </activity>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

</application>
```

What need I do?
Thanks for help :D

Comment: In the goWrite method... It doesn't say exactly where the NPE is

Comment: The logcat should include the callstack (with line numbers)...

Comment: Oops missed this, the problem is in the sdFile declaration line